# dd из /dev/ram0 не содержит внесённых изменений

Tags: linux

Создаю ramdisk:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ram0 bs=1k count=5000
```

Форматирую в ext2:

```
$ mke2fs -m0 /dev/ram0 5000
```

Монтирую в `~/ramdisk`:

```
$ mount /dev/ram0 ~/ramdisk
```

Создаю там некоторые файлы, изменяю и т.д.

Создаю образ:

```
$ dd if=/dev/ram0 of=~/initrd bs=1k count=5000
```

Но в нем существуют только файлы, которые существовали до изменения.
Подскажите, что я делаю не так.

Comment: а что значит "файлы, которые существовали до изменения". до какого изменения ?

Comment: создал файл, создал образ, изменил, перезаписал образ

Comment: вот слово "изменил" в последнем сообщении, что изменили ?

Comment: файл в папке ramdisk

Comment: А после того как файл поменяли вы /dev/ram0 размонтировали перед копированием в образ или хотя бы два раза `sync` дали, что бы бефера ОС на файловую систему точно сбросились ?

Comment: Нет. Тогда вопрос - как это делается?

Comment: просто в командной строке пишите `sync; sync`

Comment: Но все таки перед созданием конечного образа лучше ~/ramdisk размонтировать. Копирование образа диска монтированной системы не гарантирует его целостность. как минимум в файле он будет с меткой "смонтирован" в суперблоке и при последующем использовании этого файла ext2 может захотет делать его восстановление

Comment: Кстати, если в ядре включен `CONFIG_BLK_DEV_LOOP` можно вообще без рамдисков обойтись а работать с файлом образа как с устройством

Comment: @Mike, насколько я понимаю, одного вызова программы *sync* более чем достаточно. вызов *sync* дважды подряд — это такой «мем от линуса» четверть-вековой давности. где-то в рассылке он написал, что так делает перед отмонтированием. кстати, возможно это было и актуально в ту пору, а сейчас перед отмонтированием вызов *sync* вообще не требуется — буферы ввода/вывода и так сбрасываются для отмонтируемой файловой системы.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin при отмонтировании не нужен конечно. это просто быстрое решение, если хочется по какой то причине скопировать монитрованный образ. А два sync это перестраховка, от слишком быстро выполняемой следующей команды. sync может завершится до того, как все буфера будут сброшены. А вот второй sync будет ждать пока предыдущий сброс на самом деле не завершится. Хотя да, этим сведениям много лет, может что то и изменилось

Comment: @Mike, *sync может завершится до того, как все буфера будут сброшены* — насколько мне известно, не может.

Comment: Помогло размонтировать /dev/ram0 и смонтировать заново

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Ну в `man 2 sync` написано, что системный вызов sync() может вернуть управление раньше. В одной из версий man на команду sync так же есть такая информация https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=sync&category=8&russian=0  на счет двух sync помогают ли они информация расплывчатая, кое где рекомендуют вызывать его трижды :)

Comment: @Mike, *в man 2 sync написано* — «According to the standard specification (e.g., POSIX.1-2001), sync() schedules the writes, but may return  before  the  actual  writing  is done.   **However,  since  version  1.3.20  Linux does actually wait.  (This still does not guarantee data integrity: modern disks have large caches.)**» // так что **нынче** можно вызывать лишь один раз, а **для гарантии целостности**, конечно, лучше отмонтировать файловую систему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

перед созданием образа надо либо вызвать программу [*sync*](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=sync&category=8&russian=0) для сброса буферов ввода/вывода на файловые системы, либо, лучше, вообще отмонтировать файловую систему:

```
$ sudo umount /dev/ram0
```